# Old line voltage thermostats - Cen you help identifying model/maker?

Tags: thermostat, radiant-heating

Just purchased a ~40 yr old home with ceiling radiant heaters. There are 6 zones controlled by old thermostats. Zones are paired in the electrical panel (see pic).
Is there a way to easily identify the thermostat type/model from the pictures that I include? I suspect that the White-Rodgers is a DPST. I can't find any picture that resembles the remaining 5. The dial has a "Chill" position.

Can you also suggest programmable thermostats to replace the old ones?

Thanks[image: Old mystery LV thermostat][image: White-Rodgers Thermostat][image: Electrical Panel]

Comment: Is the first one embedded _in_ the wall? Can you take covers off of them to see if there are any markings inside?

Comment: Turn off the circuits and remove the thermostats from the wall junction box. Markings are expected on the backs.

Comment: First one appears to have been painted, many times. Will take some work to find the screw-heads under the paint, evidently.

Comment: We don't do product recommendations, but regardless, the feasibility of programmable thermostats will depend on how the wiring has been done.  So we'll need to see the insides of the junction boxes.  By the way, if you're willing to covert the heaters to relay control and put a bit of "thermostat cable" in the walls, it's possible to use a Nest and other very advanced thermostats.

Comment: You may have single pole thermostats I used to see this all the time in the Pacific Northwest there is usually a 4 square box and a single gang mud ring but they are usually 30 amp 240 v.  Note it is very common to find single pole in the PNW , if you turn the thermostat off and there is still voltage at the heater single pole or 2 separate elements that is how it is being controlled. If there is no voltage it may be a double pole switch.

Comment: Thanks. All 6 thermostats have an "OFF" position. Shouldn't this be a clue that they are all double pole?